# How to use strings in a column of a table to filter another table and put the amount of the filtered row in a new column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables that I'm working on now. Table 1 has a column that contains IDs and table 2 has a column that contains sentences with ID inside of it.

Example:

Table 1
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/krYS6.png)

Table 2
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWbH8.png)

I want to add two new columns to table 1. The first new column should show the amount of the rows in table 2 where the ID of that row in the table 1 is mentioned. The second new column should show the names of everyone who mentions the ID of that row in the table 1. The modified table 1 should look like this

Table 1 modified
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQ3U3.png)

Is this possible with SQL-server?
For the first new column, I was thinking about using pattern matching to filter rows of the Table 2 and count the filtered rows.

```
SELECT COUNT(Sentence)
FROM [Table 2]
WHERE Sentence LIKE '%' + '33 C 33' + '%';
```

--> This would give me 2 but how can I apply this to each row of the column?

For the second new column I still don't know if it's possible. All I could found on Google is about joining tables. Thanks a lot in advance for your answers.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to join the tables using `LIKE`, then group up by `ID` and return a count and an aggregated list.

```sql
SELECT
  t1.ID,
  Amount = COUNT(*),
  Names = STRING_AGG(t2.Name, ' ,')
FROM Table1 t1
JOIN Table2 t2 ON t2.Sentence LIKE '%' + T1.ID + '%'
GROUP BY
  t1.ID;
```

Cannot test because you haven't provided proper sample data.

Comment: Thank you very much! That did the job. I didn't know that JOIN can be used with LIKE too.

Comment: Pleasure. If the answer helped you, instead of thanking, consider upvoting and/or accepting it (by clicking the check mark)